# Labels disappear while zooming

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geowebcache

We are using GeoServer 2.10.0. While displaying the labels in the maps, the labels which are there on the border of the tiles(4*4) are not getting displayed properly. the labels can be seen after further zooming in or out(when they fall in the center of the tile and not in the border). in this image you can see the labels are being cut

On zooming further, the labels come properly, as expected

In the first image, the labels are cut.

[image: 1.png]

But in the second image, we see on zooming further, the labels are shown as expected.

[image: 2.png]

Please see the SLD.

SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>pxs_gna_mobile_site</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Geo_Style_pxs_gna_mobile_site</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Geo_Rule_pxs_gna_mobile_site</Name>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>350000.0</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://server:port/geoserver/styles/MobileTower_green.png"/>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>40</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>

          <TextSymbolizer>
                   <Geometry>
  <ogc:Function name="centroid">
    <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>candidate_code</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
                <Displacement>
                  <DisplacementX>5</DisplacementX>
                  <DisplacementY>5</DisplacementY>
                </Displacement>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
                <Radius>2</Radius>
                <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
            </Halo>         
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
             <VendorOption name="spaceAround">-1</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
        <Name>Geo_Rule_pxs_gna_mobile_site</Name>
          <MinScaleDenominator>350000.0</MinScaleDenominator>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://server:port/geoserver/styles/MobileTower_green.png"/>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>40</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Please add the code how you call the Layer from OpenLayers.

Comment: use partials vendor option

Comment: I have already used the partials vendor option. But it didn't work. @IanTurton  Also I have mentioned in the description that it is not the duplicate of the mentioned question. We do not require any solution involving GeoWebCache.

Comment: @bennos the tiles are getting cut in Geoserver layer preview as well. So it is not a open Layer issue.

Comment: Please show your SLD - partials does not require GWC

Comment: please find the SLD:

Comment: Do not add images of text, please add the text of sld

Comment: Try to use gutter when calling the WMS. There is an option you can use in WMS. Second thing is the size of meta-tiles. Look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198450/need-clarification-on-geoserver-meta-tile) for additional information. Next question: how does it look when you call a single tile? Everything all right?

Comment: @bennos Everything is alright when calling a single tile. But it highly affects the performance and hence not recommended.

Comment: @IanTurton I tried adding the text but it is not getting added due to some reason.

Comment: @bennos I have chnaaged the gutter as well. Size of meta Tiles is 4*4.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using a fixed location for your labels therefore the partials strategy is unable to work correctly as it needs to know exactly where the label is going to be drawn on each tile.

Add the following at the top of your `TextSymbolizer` to force where the label should appear:

```
<Geometry>
  <ogc:Function name="centroid">
    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
```

This, of course, assumes your geometry attribute is called `the_geom` change it if necessary to match your features. Also make sure that you have turned off your browser caching while you are testing this.
I would also remove the following as there is no telling what the interactions between all of those options is:

```
        <VendorOption name="spaceAround">-1</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">true</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
```

Comment: it didn't work. Same problem exists

Comment: please provide the text of your sld and some example data

Comment: I am unable to attache the code here. Upon attaching the code is not showing. Please suggest some other way

Comment: every one else can add code - please edit your question, paste in the code then select it and press crtl-k to format it.

Comment: I have added the code as requested.

Comment: any updates here/

Comment: did you try my suggestions

Comment: yes I tried all of your suggestions. you can find the same in SLD @ianturton

Comment: can we try with <MinScaleDenominator><MaxScaleDenominator> tags?

Comment: how to proceed on this? Did someone find any update on this.

Comment: as I said below with out your data and sld it is impossible to investigate further. You may need to purchase a support contract to solve your special case see http://geoserver.org/support/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully worked example using the states layer in GeoServer,

First with the default label placement and tiles:

[image]

Note how Wisconsin (WI) is labelled 4 times where it appears on 4 different tiles.

Now with a fixed position for the geometry in the `TextSymbbolizer`:

```
<Geometry>
  <ogc:Function name="centroid">
    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
```

[image]

Note how each state is labelled at most once but several of them are not labelled (e.g. Wisconsin) as the label will not fit on the tile so it is not drawn. Normally this would be the correct solution but since we know
there is a tile next to this one which could display the rest of the label it
would be OK to draw some of the label. GeoServer has no way of knowing this (as
each map request is independent to GeoServer) but we can let it know by adding
the `<VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>`. This tells GeoServer it can draw as much label as fits on the tile.

[image]

Comment: I have modified my SLD exactly as you mentioned above. But still same issue exists.

Comment: then you will need to provide a link to your complete datafile and SLD