# Geoserver + Boundless - web app icons being clipped

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I have created a map app, that displays a few points with their attribute data.
The problem I am facing is that the point icons get clipped  when serving the map.
I have read [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87116/geoserver-cut-off-symbols-close-to-tile-edges) as well as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18919/geoserver-vendoroption-for-sld-to-place-labels-overlapping-and-out-of-bounds/18937#18937), but none of them seem to be working for me.

This is what I get when debugging and deploying my app.

[image: Clipped Icons]

As you can see, the icons get clipped and I cannot seem to "fix" this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I hope this helps anyone else that has had the same problems as I did for whom the mentioned answers did not work...

The solution was to manually stretch the bounding box max and min X/Y coordinates.
The ones computed from the data put some of the points right on the edge, stretching the bbox ensured that the features with their icons were rendered correctly.

If you are unsure of where to set this, it is part of the initial layer set up.

[image: bbox]

Here are the points being rendered correctly:

[image: fixed features]